# Triggering Google script with specific time slot

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to trigger a google script every 15 min in specific time slots, which are 9:30am - 4:30pm and 9:30pm - 5:30am, Monday to Friday only.

I want the script to send email when it is triggered. I write some codes (searching from google) and it successfully sends email to me, but I don’t know how to trigger the script in specific time slots I mentioned above. It is my first time try to write codes and I don’t know how to do it. I google for it, but my code doesn’t work. So, I come here looking for help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: You'll probably have to set up a trigger for once every 15 minutes and use logic to select the desired time slots which will require you to understand how to use Javascript Date() object

Answer (score 1):

### It is not feasible (or very convoluted) to set up an Apps Script trigger for specific time slots

Much easier is to set it up as [everyMinutes(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn) and then implement a conditional statement within the function run on trigger to decide either the email shall be sent or not

Sample (compare it carefully against the conditions you want to implement):

```js
//run only once:
function createTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("runOnTrigger")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(15)
  .create();
}
function runOnTrigger(){
  var date = new Date();
  var weekDay = date.getDay();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();

  //stop execution if it's a weekday
  if(weekDay == 0 || weekDay == 6){
    return;
  }
  // stop execution if it's between 4:30pm and 9:30pm
  if(((hours == 16 && minutes >= 30) || hours >= 17) && ((hours == 21 && minutes <= 30) || hours < 21)){
    return;
  }
// stop execution if it's between 9:30pm and 5:30 am
  if(((hours == 5 && minutes >= 30) || hours > 6) && ((hours == 16 && minutes <= 30) || hours < 16)){
    return;
  }
// implement here your request (e.g. sending emails) that shall be run if you are in the correc time slot
}
```